# Mirror to Multiple Ports Using TC?

Tags: linux, tc

Does anyone know if it's possible to mirror to multiple interfaces from one source interface using TC? I've done the following:

1. The first thing I did was create an ingress queue on my input interface with `tc qdisc add dev e101-001-0 handle ffff: ingress`

   11. If you need to delete a qdisc you can do it with `tc qdisc del dev e101-001-0 [ root | ingress ]`
2. Double check your queue with handle ffff was created with `tc -s qdisc ls dev e101-001-0`
3. Next we want to mirror all traffic from the ingress port to an output port with `tc filter add dev e101-001-0 parent ffff: protocol all u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress mirror dev e101-005-0`
4. Check that your port mirror appeared in the config with `tc -s -p filter ls dev e101-001-0 parent ffff:`

   41. If you need to delete the filters you can do so with `tc filter del dev e101-001-0 parent ffff:`
5. Set queue to not shape traffic with `tc qdisc add dev e101-001-0 handle 1: root prio`

That got it working outputting to one interface, but I noticed if I add another filter with a new interface the first interface stops receiving traffic and it all goes to the new interface.

Comment: Would several `iptables` TEE rules be an option instead of `tc`?

Comment: Sure! That would work just as well.

Comment: The only caveat is that there isn't a target IP to send to - it just needs to mirror it to a local interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [tc action](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-actions.8) can have a control operator appended to alter further handling of packets:

> CONTROL
>      The CONTROL indicates how tc should proceed after executing the action. Any of the following are valid:
>
> reclassify
>      Restart the classifiction by jumping back to the first filter attached to the action's parent.
>
> **pipe**
>      Continue with the next action. This is the default control.
>
> drop
>      Drop the packed without running any further actions.
>
> **continue**
>      Continue the classification with the next filter.
>
> pass
>      Return to the calling qdisc for packet processing, and end classification of this packet.

It seems that after a matching filter no further filter is evaluated.

What you can simply do:

- You can combine (*pipe*) multiple actions on the same filter (let's suppose the 2nd mirror interface is called *e101-006-0*):

  ```
  tc filter add dev e101-001-0 ingress u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress mirror dev e101-005-0 pipe action mirred egress mirror dev e101-006-0
  ```
- You can also, instead, chain multiple filters (using action's *continue* control). Then an explicit *prio/pref* should be given because the order of filters will matter: the filter having the action with the *continue* control must be evaluated first.

  ```
  tc filter add dev e101-001-0 ingress pref 1 u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress mirror dev e101-005-0 continue
  tc filter add dev e101-001-0 ingress pref 2 u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress mirror dev e101-006-0
  ```

  This would be used over the 1st method if for example you'd want a different filter between the two actions (eg: one could match *protocol ip* the other *protocol ipv6*).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a workaround, but I realized I could just pump the traffic to a bridge instead and that effectively did the same thing. I'm open to better suggestions though.